# CPU suddenly overheating

Tags: cpu, cooling

One day, when I woke up and turned my computer on, it suddenly just became so slow, when I move the mouse it hangs then moves, hangs then moves, i turned off my pc and touch the insides of my cpu and realized it was overheating. This never happened to me before, all the fans are working fine, and I did nothing to my computer for this to happen. I tried reformatting my PC and it worked fine. But when I plug my usb dongle, it suddenly goes slow again and it overheats again. But my keyboard and mouse which are connected via USB doesn't have this problem. It also suddenly says that the usb port is 1.0 (for some ports) even if they're all 2.0 (Only when I plug my usb dongle). How should I troubleshoot/fix this? I currently have this large fan facing my CPU right now which is aweful.

Comment: Pop the side off the case and blow out all the dust, especially around any fans.  Also make sure you don't have a carpet of dust between the CPU heatsink and fan.

Comment: Not clear if you've eliminated a defective USB device as the culprit.  Try using the USB dongle, whatever it is, in another machine.

Comment: Indeed, the computer is most likely not overheating, and the USB dongle is causing the problem. Can you give some details on what exactly this "USB dongle" is (manufacturer, model name or number, what it does, etc.)? You could Google the issue along with the model name or number to see if this is a common issue.

Comment: It's `zte mf-627`. I checked the heat when the usb dongle is not connected and it's seems that the processor is still hot. I just brushed the fans thoroughly and blew as hard as I could to remove dirt my brush couldn't reach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is overheating problem..
Still, confirm it using Speedfan(CPU temperatures below 60 deg Celsius are okay).

As far as USB ports are concerned, don't use a dongle for USB. Especially for devices like pen drives and hard drives.

To me, dongle seems to be the culprit.

Hav you tried operating the keyboard? I mean, is it just the mouse that lags of it is entire PC?